# How do I toggle the visibility of an element based on the value of a boolean field that default to 'checked'?

Tags: visualforce

I have a field that is rendered like so:

```
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Event.fields.Customer_Facing_Event__c.Label}" for="{!event.Customer_Facing_Event__c}" />
           <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
              <apex:inputField value="{!event.Customer_Facing_Event__c}">  
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  reRender="pbs_customerToMeet"/>
              </apex:inputField>
          </apex:actionRegion>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

This is a boolean field that defaults to true. I'd like to use the value of this field to toggle the visibility of a `Page Block Section`, like so:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="CUSTOMER TO MEET" collapsible="false" id="pbs_customerToMeet" 
         rendered="{!event.Customer_Facing_Event__c}">  
      {!event.Customer_Facing_Event__c} 
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The problem is that, although the field defaults to `true`, it appears that the value of the field is in fact `false`, and Salesforce instead just renders the input as `checked`. This causes my `PageBlockSection` to not be visible on the initial page render.

How can I make the section render initially?

Comment: one thing to be aware of is that the `immediate="true"` will cause no data from your form to be posted back to the controller, including the value of the checkbox `event.Customer_Facing_Event__c`. If you remove this attribute does the behavior change?

Comment: are you saying that a) the pageblockSectionItem inputField renders as checked but the pageBlockSection does not render on page load? and b) is there a controller extension involved and how does it instantiate the getter for `event`?

Comment: a) yes, that is my problem. b) there is a controller extension for this page, the event property on the controller is populated as so: `(Event)controller.getRecord();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit `pbs_customerToMeet` **parent element** in your `reRender` call

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: `pbs_customerToMeet` is `pageBlockSection`, and in you case it is not rendered initially, so when you have `reRender="pbs_customerToMeet"` it's not going to be rerender. I suggested to modify `reRender` from `actionSupport` to use `pbs_customerToMeet`'s parent element which in your case would be `pageBlock`. It has to be like `reRender="YourPageBlockName"`

Comment: Ah ok, got it now. But the problem is not what happens when actionSupport executes, the problem is the fact that the value of the field is false even though it is configured to default to true. It would appear that when a Boolean field is configured to default to true, salesforce simply renders the checkbox as ticked as opposed to setting the value of the field to true.

Comment: It looks like defaults are set on a Database level. Here is workaround: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/75383/12440

Comment: It would look like that workaround would indeed work for me, but the `Event` object does not appear to have a property called `sObjectType` on it. This means that the line: `this.event = Event.sObjectType.newSObject(null, true);` fails to compile with the error `Invalid field sobjecttype for SObject Event`