# How to get the default value for a Long Text Area field?

Tags: apex, custom-field

Im trying to pull in the default value set in the configuration for a Long Text Area field we created on the Case object. How do we retrieve that value through Apex? The following returns a "null".

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.CustomField__c;
f = f.getSObjectField().getDescribe();
System.debug('Default Value is: ' + f.getDefaultValue());
```

The debug returns "null", so

> "Default Value is: null".

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? What's not working? Also, what is the default value set to?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The debug returns "null", so "Default Value is: null". It just has some standard text in it that the user will do multiple things with, including copying and pasting multiple versions of that same text in that field.

Comment: Is it plain text or a formula?

Comment: Mostly text, but uses the BR() function for line breaks. So a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is unclear in this, but here go two options:

1. You can try `.getDefaultValueFormula()`. The documentation for this is "glorious":

   > Returns the default value specified for this field if a formula is not used.

   But what it means that it will return the value with the formula configured.
2. Alternatively, and I repurposed @AdrianLarson's answer from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97278/what-does-describefieldresult-getdefaultvalue-actually-return), you can do this:

   ```
   Case defaults = (Case) Case.sObjectType.newSObject(/*recordTypeId*/ null, /*loadDefaultValues*/ true);

   System.debug(Case.CustomField__c);
   ```

   I don't thing it performs as well but should do the trick

Comment: I was wondering if we should flag as a dupe.

Comment: It’s marginal. I think there might be enough difference with your original post that merits its own question.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you both! I used #2.